# Passing JSON to Jade and using the same data for API access

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code as a schema module:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Module.find(function (err, modules) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.json(modules);
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 500;

            log.error('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, err.message);

            return res.json({
                error: 'Server error'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And this works fine for my API, but I'm also trying to use this data to load it into my Jade template.

```
var modules = require('./routes/modules');

// home page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { modules: modules })
});

app.use('/api/modules', modules);
```

But this just doesn't work, it gives me undefined as if it doesn't exist (when logged).

If I modify my router to the following:

```
res.render('index', {
    modules: modules
})
```

It works fine for getting the data but not when accessing it through my API.

So my question, how can I use this particular piece of code for my API and for rendering it to the Jade template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of modules as the middleware is not correct. i.e.

```
app.use('/api/modules', modules);
```

As specified in the http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html, your middleware should call the next() function.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now());
  next();
});
```

To solve this, you should define your route similar to the index route, but you will use res.send.

```
var modules = require('./routes/modules');

// home page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { modules: modules })
});

app.get('/api/modules', function(req, res) {
    res.send({ modules: modules })
});
```

Comment: Why should I use next? and does using res.send work for both as opposed to having two separate methods?

Comment: res.send is different from res.render.. I have updated the code.